# Change windows Start menu installed application hover over text

Tags: c#

I have published and installed my C# Clickonce application.

But when going to windows start menu, all programs, then clicking on my applications folder and hovering the mouse over the application, the text shown is:

Type: ClickOnce Application Reference
Size 909322334547832 bytes
Date modified: 20/10/2015 12:45:00 p.m.

How can i change to no text or my applications name?

This is so people installing my application see something nicer and makes more sense to them (less scary).

Comment: Your application is 900TB?

Comment: I added a few extra numbers. I wondered if anybody would notice.